# Ubuntu 20.04 constantly drops wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa

Since a few days, my laptop with an intel 9560ac and Ubuntu 20.04 (livepatch on and up to date), started constantly dropping the wifi. Every 5 seconds on average. It asks for the password, connects, drops, asks for the password, over and over. This never happened before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I found out with `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` but I can't make heads or tails out of it. The router didn't change, it's a TP-Link Deco M4.

**UPDATE**

It has something to do with the TP-Link Deco M4. if I connect to another wifi (from a Netgear), everything works normally. If I try to connect to the Guest network from the Deco (with no password), I get no issues either.
So apparently, it has something to do with the authentication. I have that wifi configured for WPA & WPA2 Personal and automatic IPV6.

---

```
sep 25 11:49:52 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027392.4189] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
sep 25 11:49:52 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027392.4189] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
sep 25 11:49:52 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027392.4318] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
sep 25 11:49:52 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027392.4318] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
sep 25 11:49:56 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <warn>  [1601027396.5121] sup-iface[0x563245dc7210,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
sep 25 11:49:56 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027396.5172] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
sep 25 11:49:56 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027396.5176] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
sep 25 11:49:56 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027396.5177] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
sep 25 11:49:56 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027396.5181] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
sep 25 11:49:56 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027396.6173] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
sep 25 11:49:56 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027396.6173] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
sep 25 11:49:56 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027396.7215] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
sep 25 11:49:56 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027396.7215] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.7926] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.7931] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.7943] device (wlo1): disconnecting for new activation request.
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.7944] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="6df5bc60-2d2b-49d8-824b-79712bcf2c44" name="codenet" pid=2468 uid=1000 result="success"
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <warn>  [1601027397.7996] device (wlo1): Deactivation failed: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.NotConnected: This interface is not connected
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.7996] device (wlo1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8005] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'codenet' (6df5bc60-2d2b-49d8-824b-79712bcf2c44)
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8013] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8016] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8019] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8039] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'codenet' has security, but secrets are required.
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8039] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8041] sup-iface[0x563245dc7210,wlo1]: wps: type pbc start...
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8063] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8066] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8069] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'codenet' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8069] Config: added 'ssid' value 'codenet'
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8069] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8069] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8069] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.8070] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.9236] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.9236] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> authenticating
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.9679] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.9679] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.9837] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
sep 25 11:49:57 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027397.9838] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
sep 25 11:49:58 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027398.0208] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
sep 25 11:49:58 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027398.0209] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
sep 25 11:50:02 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <warn>  [1601027402.1023] sup-iface[0x563245dc7210,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
sep 25 11:50:02 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027402.1074] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
sep 25 11:50:02 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027402.1079] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
sep 25 11:50:02 winston-wolfe NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1601027402.1079] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```